# How can I compute the following conditional expectation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

> I know that $X,Y$ are two independent random variables. This random variables have the uniform distribution on $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ where $n\geq 2$. Now I consider $\Bbb{E}(X|X+Y)$. I could show that $\Bbb{E}(X|X+Y)=\frac{1}{6}n(n^2-1)$.

Now in addition I know that $\Bbb{E}(X|X+Y)$ is $\sigma(X+Y)$-measurable, i.e. there exists a measurable function $g$ such that $g(X+Y)=\Bbb{E}(X|X+Y)$. Now I would like to find this $g$ but I don't see how. Because I have an explicit expression for $\Bbb{E}(X|X+Y)$ but not depending on $x,y$.

Could maybe someone help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I suspect there is a mistake in your expression for $\mathbb{E}[X|X+Y]$.  If $n=3$, $\frac{1}{6}n(n^2-1)=4$, but since $X \le 3$ we can't have $\mathbb{E}[X|X+Y] = 4$.

Comment: @user6247850 oh no really?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a nice way to compute this. We have
$$\mathbb E[X+Y|X+Y]=X+Y$$
because $X+Y$ is $\sigma(X+Y)$-measurable. But by linearity and identical distribution
$$\mathbb E[X+Y|X+Y]=\mathbb E[X|X+Y]+\mathbb E[Y|X+Y]=2\mathbb E[X|X+Y].$$

Therefore, $\mathbb E[X|X+Y]=\frac{X+Y}{2}$. No information about the distribution needed.

EDIT: Apparently some information is needed, the independence seems to be necessary for this to hold. See counter example below.

Comment: But where does my way fails? Because I would like to compute it in my way.

Comment: so I mean where does the computation fails to get to $\frac{1}{6}n(n^2-1)$

Comment: @Haveaniceday You should ask a separate question, where you show your work in detail, and ask where the mistake is.

Comment: Without going into details: $\mathbb E[X|X+Y]$ is a random variable, while $\frac16 n(n^2-1)$ is a real number. There is something conceptually to rectify.

Comment: I think you also need independence to get $\mathbb{E}[X|X+Y] = \mathbb{E}[Y|X+Y]$. 
 Otherwise one could think about their joint distributions being set up in a way to get different values there.

Comment: But they are identically distributed?

Comment: @PeterKeller Sure, but I don't see any way to conclude $\mathbb{E}[X|X+Y]=\mathbb{E}[Y|X+Y]$ from identical distributions without knowledge of their joint distribution.

Comment: I think i need some more explicit computations to follow you there.

Comment: Okay, here's a counterexample on a 3 point probability space with uniform measure.  $X(\omega_1)=1=Y(\omega_2)$, $X(\omega_2)=0=Y(\omega_3)$, $X(\omega_3)=-1=Y(\omega_1)$.  It's clear $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed, but $(X+Y)(\omega_1)=0$, $(X+Y)(\omega_2)=1$, and $(X+Y)(\omega_3)=-1$, so $X$ and $Y$ are both $\sigma(X+Y)$ measurable.